# Question regarding property of limsup

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(s_n)$ be a bounded sequence and let $m=\lim \sup s_n$. Then $m \in S$, where $S$ is the set of subsequential limits of $(s_n)$. Show that there exists a subsequence of $(s_n)$ that converges to m.

I know I have to use the following theorem to prove it:

> Let $(s_n)$ be a bounded sequence and let $m=\lim \sup s_n$. Then
>   following properties hold:
>
> - For every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that $n \ge N$ implies that $s_n < m+\epsilon$.
> - For every $\epsilon > 0$ and for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists an integer $k>i$ such that $s_k > m- \epsilon$.
>
> Furthermore, if $m$ is a real number satisfying above properties then
>   $m=\lim \sup s_n$.

The answer says it follows from both the properties but I'm unable to follow. I need few more hints.

Comment: Try to construct the subsequence by using smaller and smaller epsilons.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Q_0 := (s_n)$. For each $j > 0$, let $Q_j = \{ x \in Q_{j-1} \mid |x - m |< 1/j\}$. Show that the $Q_j$ are always non-empty.

Do you see where to go from there?

Comment: $Q_j$ is non empty because $m \in Q_j$ for all $j$. Here's my proof: Now, pick $n_k$ such that $n_k$ satisfies property (a) and (b)  and since $Q_k$ is not empty$, we have $m-1/k < s_{n_k} < m+1/k$. Is it correct?

Comment: As the $Q_j$ satisfy $\{s_n\} = Q_0 \supseteq Q_1 \supseteq Q_2 \supseteq ...$, we could only have $m \in Q_j$ if $m$ happened to be an element of the sequence $\{s_n\}$, so no, you are mistaken. It is the properties of the lim sup that show that the $Q_j$ are never empty. An in fact, they must all be infinite.